# Multiple Select Change color of SVG with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to change the colors of multiple SVG paths with jQuery and a multiple select. I can change the color initially but when the option is deselected, the SVG still has the color change. https://codepen.io/handsomemeatball/pen/zYGvrNy

For example, if I select Seattle and Bellevue but then unselect each value, the color of the path/polygon is still red. How do I only highlight the selected values?

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("select")
    .change(function() {
      var value = jQuery(this)
        .children(":selected")
        .val();
      jQuery("svg")
        .find("#" + value)
        .css("fill", "red");
    })
    .change();
});
```

```css
svg {width:400px;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="item_meta[82][]" id="field_trf7c" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." aria-required="true" data-invmsg="Service Area is invalid" data-sectionid="49" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select options" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="Seattle" class="">
   Seattle  </option>
   <option value="Tacoma" class="">
   Tacoma  </option>
   <option value="Bellevue" class="">
   Bellevue  </option>
   <option value="Everett" class="">
   Everett  </option>
   <option value="Arlington" class="">
   Arlington  </option>
   <option value="Auburn" class="">
   Auburn  </option>
   <option value="Bainbridge Island" class="">
   Bainbridge Island  </option>
   <option value="Beaux Arts Village" class="">
   Beaux Arts Village  </option>
   <option value="Bonney Lake" class="">
   Bonney Lake  </option>
   <option value="Bothell" class="">
   Bothell  </option>
   <option value="Bremerton" class="">
   Bremerton  </option>
   <option value="Brier" class="">
   Brier  </option>
   <option value="Burien" class="">
   Burien  </option>
   <option value="Covington" class="">
   Covington  </option>
   <option value="Des Moines" class="">
   Des Moines  </option>
   <option value="Duvall" class="">
   Duvall  </option>
   <option value="Enumclaw" class="">
   Enumclaw  </option>
   <option value="Edmonds" class="">
   Edmonds  </option>
   <option value="Federal Way" class="">
   Federal Way  </option>
   <option value="Gig Harbor" class="">
   Gig Harbor  </option>
   <option value="Gold Bar" class="">
   Gold Bar  </option>
   <option value="Granite Falls" class="">
   Granite Falls  </option>
   <option value="Issaquah" class="">
   Issaquah  </option>
   <option value="Kenmore" class="">
   Kenmore  </option>
   <option value="Kent" class="">
   Kent  </option>
   <option value="Kirkland" class="">
   Kirkland  </option>
   <option value="Lake Forest Park" class="">
   Lake Forest Park  </option>
   <option value="Lake Stevens" class="">
   Lake Stevens  </option>
   <option value="Lakewood" class="">
   Lakewood  </option>
   <option value="Lynnwood" class="">
   Lynnwood  </option>
   <option value="Maple Valley" class="">
   Maple Valley  </option>
   <option value="Marysville" class="">
   Marysville  </option>
   <option value="Mercer Island" class="">
   Mercer Island  </option>
   <option value="Mill Creek" class="">
   Mill Creek  </option>
   <option value="Monroe" class="">
   Monroe  </option>
   <option value="Mountlake Terrace" class="">
   Mountlake Terrace  </option>
   <option value="Mount Vernon" class="">
   Mount Vernon  </option>
   <option value="Mukilteo" class="">
   Mukilteo  </option>
   <option value="Newcastle" class="">
   Newcastle  </option>
   <option value="Normandy Park" class="">
   Normandy Park  </option>
   <option value="Puyallup" class="">
   Puyallup  </option>
   <option value="Poulsbo" class="">
   Poulsbo  </option>
   <option value="Redmond" class="">
   Redmond  </option>
   <option value="Renton" class="">
   Renton  </option>
   <option value="Sammamish" class="">
   Sammamish  </option>
   <option value="SeaTac" class="">
   SeaTac  </option>
   <option value="Shoreline" class="">
   Shoreline  </option>
   <option value="Silverdale" class="">
   Silverdale  </option>
   <option value="Snohomish" class="">
   Snohomish  </option>
   <option value="Stanwood" class="">
   Stanwood  </option>
   <option value="Sultan" class="">
   Sultan  </option>
   <option value="Tukwila" class="">
   Tukwila  </option>
   <option value="Woodinville" class="">
   Woodinville  </option>
   <option value="Woodway" class="">
   Woodway  </option>
  </select>
<svg version="1.1" id="Washington" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="173.42 47.54 345.26 470.5" enable-background="new 173.42 47.54 345.26 470.5" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#878787" d="M175.68,47.54h-2.26v8.83l1.05-1.09l1.5-4.73L175.68,47.54z M203.46,176.14l-2.05-7.83l-3.1-7.74l-1.71-1.46
 h-2.05l-2.22,1.71l3.68,4.19l2.22,6.15l-0.04,4.81l-3.1,0.29l-0.84-2.09l-0.58-6.78l-1.34-2.17l-2.05,0.12l-0.42,2.64l0.88,5.9
 l1.25,4.22l2.85,6.19l3.68,4.81l4.02,0.17l1.75-5.23L203.46,176.14z M214.33,226.63l-11.08-14.6l-0.96-2.68l-0.67-6.73l-0.55-2.51
 l-1.5-1.8l-4.06-2.68l-1.72-2.01l-8.99-16.19l-1.34-4.64l-0.96-2.01l-1.93-2.38l-1.59-3.14l0.09-4.44l1.5-1.92l5.23-2.97l2.05-1.59
 l-4.22-7.61l-5.27-0.05l-4.94,2.56v99.27l0.13-3.06l2.51-4.18l1.42,11.59l-0.17,9.37l-3.89,20.25v10.41l1.3,0.59l2.46-0.5l2.35-1.47
 l1.8-2.38l0.67-3.31l0.54-5.14l1.38-6.07l3.93-11.54l2.97-6.28l9.46-12.09l1.75-3.35l1.59-5.98l1.8-2.76l2.09-0.54l6.36-0.34
 l1.76-1.29L214.33,226.63z M233.95,341l-0.12-0.29l-3.56,4.68L209.36,341l0.75-3.68l-7.57,3.68l1.17-3.18l4.06-4.43l2.05-3.31
 l1.79-3.97l-0.04-0.71h-1.63l-7.45-4.23l-1.79-1.92l-1.22-4.27l-0.25-4.1l0.5-3.47l1.13-2.97l0.25-0.38l-4.01-10.33l4.47-7.61
 l-10.58-11.97l-1.55,3.98l-3.01,14.09l-1.38,4.15L182.5,299l-4.85,2.85l-4.23,1.71v82.12l2.64-3.89l-1.18,4.39l0.97,2.3l1.8,1.59
 l1.42,2.22l1.17,4.39l0.33,2.39l0.09,8.66l-0.55,5.94l-1.92,4.89l-4.1,1.97v7.32l3.43,14.39l5.56,9.96l6.32-5.86l0.08-1.88
 l-0.58-2.22l-0.71-1.8l-0.34-0.67l0.71-1.34l1.18-1.63l0.96-0.71l0.04,1.55l1.25-2.64l1.38-1.42l0.21-1.84l-5.18-9.04l-1.13-4.35
 l0.96-4.43l3.3-5.4l0.84-2.51l0.25-3.14l0.42-2.63l1.42-1.13l1.88-0.84l1.59-1.88l1.47-2.26l1.67-1.84l7.41-3.85l2.76-2.93
 l1.59-5.85l1.13,7.74l-2.3,5.27l-3.18,4.39l-1.59,5.19l-1.8,4.14l-2.97,2.84l-0.63,2.85l5.4,4.18l16.52,7.41l3.18,0.04l2.47-6.4
 l-0.8-5.23l-5.35-11l3.68-1.22l2.85-2.01l2.17-3.09l1.59-4.39l-3.97-6.74l0.96-6.94l2.84-7.37l1.68-8.03l1.67-5.9l2.8-6.65
 l0.38-5.48L233.95,341z M241.65,47.54l-0.58,0.33l-1.09-0.33h-33.97l-0.75,2.01l-2.14,2.05l-1,2.8l2.09,5.27l2.51,2.34l3.26,0.8
 l3.43-0.46l3.18-1.51l1.63-1.96l3.43-5.74l1.55-1.21l2.18,0.21l3.26,1l1.46,1.97l-3.17,3.35v2.38l2.88,2.76l4.23,8.58l2.34,1.8
 l3.51,0.29l3.14,0.96l2.76,1.68l4.98,5.52l6.36,3.93l4.64,4.23h94.13v17.9h79.11v50.62h15.43v84l58.74,7.82l-26.69,39.2
 l-63.38,14.14v31.96l2.8,28.12l28.53,2.13v31.08l-25.72-5.14l-42.34-14.27l-5.44,42.75l22.05,15.27v62.04h-79.24l-56.64-39.74
 h-30.12v-15.98l-3.22,0.46l-3.18-3.47l-0.63,1.38l-17.23,25.39l-7.16,7.41l-7.78,4.68l-0.83-3.43l-2.01-3.47l-2.64-2.68l-5.23-2.42
 l-2-3.1l-1.68-3.56l-1.75-2.67l-4.06-2.51l-0.17,0.25v63.29h346.13V47.54H241.65z M203.79,451.15l-2.13-1.3l-4.23-0.46l-2.72,0.46
 l-1.21,2.68l-1.17,3.05l-1.84,1.34l-1.8,1.34l0.92,3.1l0.88,0.42l3.01,3.13l1.8,1.34l1.84,1.3h1.21l2.39-1.76l2.76-3.09l0.88-4.9
 l0.29-3.05L203.79,451.15z"/>
<g>
 <polygon id="Whidbey_Island" fill="#FC9A1A" points="273.9,207.3 273.32,208.77 272.06,210.02 270.31,213.24 270.26,213.33 268.13,217.26 
  267.13,218.68 266.37,220.86 265.37,221.78 264.03,221.73 263.66,220.06 263.45,218.09 262.44,217.26 257.8,219.39 255,220.02 
  253.74,218.43 253.28,211.61 251.94,204.5 249.64,198.64 246.29,195.76 243.66,196.3 239.73,200.86 237.47,202.32 234.75,201.95 
  232.87,200.44 230.98,197.97 228.01,195.63 224.12,190.02 221.32,183.54 221.57,178.23 217.81,172.37 216.72,167.77 219.86,150.2 
  218.35,142.71 215,139.62 210.44,140.24 205.3,143.71 200.03,134.26 198.6,132.8 196.39,132.08 193.58,130.29 190.86,128.07 
  189.19,126.1 186.68,118.49 187.64,111.96 205.3,75.9 207.85,68.83 213.33,68.96 216.34,67.37 218.73,64.52 220.82,63.44 
  222.78,66.95 223.2,69.33 223.54,70.34 224.37,71.34 224.67,77.91 237.8,89 237.47,97.91 234.62,101.17 231.32,101.96 
  227.97,100.42 225.04,96.78 221.19,93.47 217.97,96.32 215.55,101.8 214.04,106.48 211.11,99.87 209.94,102.13 209.56,107.95 
  208.94,112 205.84,114.51 193.54,117.15 196.43,121.08 199.4,121.54 206.01,119.53 208.85,120.29 213.83,123.38 216.3,124.09 
  220.86,126.23 224.04,131.62 226.09,138.69 228.72,153.04 229.56,170.61 231.28,186.18 233.66,189.73 236.51,187.77 239.06,180.4 
  236.34,173.46 236.09,166.35 238.22,162.75 242.7,166.3 246.13,170.86 249.72,174.59 266.58,186.59 269.89,191.7 271.19,199.02 
  273.07,204  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Vashon_Island" fill="#FC9A1A" points="269.6,386.27 268.01,386.35 258.76,390.28 251.98,397.52 247.76,401.08 246.63,396.93 
  246.8,392.75 248.39,389.53 251.4,388.23 253.53,386.56 254.03,383.34 252.65,380.91 249.1,381.79 250.69,383.92 246.5,385.97 
  244.33,387.44 243.41,389.28 243.32,395.6 242.86,398.61 241.94,401.08 240.48,402.58 238.97,402.41 237.3,400.74 235.42,397.94 
  234.5,394.59 235.33,391.62 236.71,389.15 237.47,387.23 239.06,363.55 240.4,359.91 243.58,355.1 247.38,351 250.69,349.41 
  249.31,353.85 250.23,355.94 252.15,357.44 253.74,360.16 254.2,363.43 254.41,369.83 255.04,373.01 257.76,378.36 261.23,381 
  265.24,382.96  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Bainbridge_Island" fill="#FC9A1A" points="245.42,322.3 243.62,324.06 241.48,327.24 236.76,326.36 232.2,319.58 228.93,318.83 
  226.17,319.42 224.62,317.7 226.38,312.47 226.8,308.83 225.29,306.24 224.33,302.81 224.04,298.29 224.37,296.28 228.01,291.18 
  228.85,287.96 228.64,284.74 228.89,282.27 231.02,281.26 233.16,281.97 235.54,283.69 237.63,285.87 238.89,287.92 239.98,298.21 
  241.32,302.81 243.37,305.15 241.65,307.58 240.52,308.71 238.89,309.46 241.15,312.1 241.07,314.48 241.86,315.94 242.28,317.7 
  242.65,320 243.62,321.47  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Seattle" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M286.16,349.41h-17.95l-1.72-2.97l-1.51-3.35l-4.06-14.22l-0.33-2.8l1.13-2.22l2.84-3.68l2.68-0.79
  l2.38,3.3l2.3,4.52l2.18,2.89l1-6.53l0.21-5.06l-1.09-4.1l-3.05-3.72l-9.54-4.31l-2.01-1.34l-2.09-2.97l-1.13-2.93l0.75-1.38
  l2.47-0.88l0.92-2.18l0.54-2.8l1.34-2.76l3.35-5.35l0.79-3.51l-0.63-5.23l-0.46-2.89h15.02c-0.88,6.15-0.21,16.82,2.34,17.74
  c3.39,1.25,4.64,0,4.73,2.26c0.13,2.3-4.6,9.45-6.44,9.16c-1.84-0.25-4.89-2.26-4.81-0.5c0.04,1.8,4.31,1.97,4.48,4.98
  c0.13,2.97-1.59,14.77-0.67,18.45c0.88,3.68,4.94,3.14,4.56,7.07C284.45,334.1,284.82,343.93,286.16,349.41z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Shoreline" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M280.56,272.02c-0.04,0.04-0.04,0.08-0.04,0.13H265.5l-0.29-2.05l-2.34-3.35l-1.59-4.69h15.77
  L280.56,272.02z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Lake_Forest_Park" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M282.77,262.06v5.61c-0.5,0.13-0.88,0.29-0.88,0.29c-0.63,0.5-1.09,2.01-1.34,4.06l-3.51-9.96H282.77z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Edmonds" fill="#FC9A1A" points="272.02,237.76 272.02,262.06 261.27,262.06 261.23,261.98 261.61,255.75 262.65,250.6 
  264.24,246.29 266.33,242.65  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Mountlake_Terrace" x="272.02" y="254.82" fill="#FC9A1A" width="10.75" height="7.24"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Kemore" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M288.38,262.06v11.63h-5.31c0-0.54,0.13-1,0.33-1.38c0.04-0.04,0.08-0.13,0.08-0.17
  c1.97-3.31,1.59-3.64,0.84-4.31c-0.42-0.33-1-0.29-1.55-0.17v-5.61H288.38z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Lynnwood" fill="#FC9A1A" points="295.07,258.26 295.07,262.06 282.77,262.06 282.77,254.82 272.02,254.82 272.02,237.76 
  294.07,237.76 286.54,250.26  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Brier" x="288.38" y="262.06" fill="#FC9A1A" width="6.69" height="11.63"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Bothell" fill="#FC9A1A" points="312.43,261.23 308.04,261.23 308.04,273.69 295.07,273.69 295.07,258.26 286.54,250.26 
  294.07,237.76 311.97,237.76  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Everett" fill="#FC9A1A" points="336.15,180.57 336.15,250.93 327.45,250.93 327.74,249.89 312.22,249.89 311.97,237.76 
  283.82,237.76 278.13,218.6 278.13,216.71 278.63,215.63 278.63,212.49 279.51,209.98 281.18,208.39 285.41,205.13 286.91,203.41 
  288.71,201.95 293.15,200.94 296.29,200.23 298.17,198.47 302.44,195.8 303.23,191.7 303.61,187.05 304.99,185.55 305.95,184.38 
  306.53,183.71 310.97,184.63 310.97,184.71 322.6,184.71 322.6,180.57  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Mukulteo" fill="#FC9A1A" points="283.82,237.76 272.02,237.76 272.65,237.21 275.41,231.94 275.95,224.96 276.58,220.02 
  278.13,216.71 278.13,218.6  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Wodinville" fill="#FC9A1A" points="327.74,249.89 325.15,259.43 312.43,261.52 312.43,273.69 308.04,273.69 308.04,261.23 
  310.72,261.23 310.72,249.89  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Kirkland" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M325.15,259.43v34.3h-28.74c-1.21-2.22-2.76-3.1-2.8-4.31c-0.08-1.42,3.3-4.23,2.34-5.77
  c-1-1.55-4.27,4.06-6.02,2.72c-0.21-0.17-0.5-0.46-0.84-0.84c-2.13-2.34-6.28-8.37-6.02-11.84h29.37v-12.17L325.15,259.43z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Mercer_Island" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M296.41,333.32c0,6.67-2.09,12.07-4.67,12.07c-2.58,0-0.94-4.23-4.67-12.07
  c-2.87-6.02,2.09-12.07,4.67-12.07C294.32,321.25,296.41,326.65,296.41,333.32z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Redmond" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M361.5,281.26v12.47h-18.32V299h-1.92c-1.09-3.51-0.46-3.6-2.72-3.26c-0.84,0.13-1.13,1.34-1.09,3.26
  h-15.81v-5.27h3.51v-11.55h15.94v-0.92H361.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Bellevue" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M341.09,339.04V341h-43.76c-0.17-5.35,4.73-7.2,4.56-10.83c-0.17-3.68-5.56-7.91-5.48-11.09
  c0.04-3.18-2.68-5.4-5.48-5.98c-0.88-0.17-1.46-1.21-1.84-2.59c-0.38-1.55-0.42-3.6,0-5.31c0.38-1.59,1.13-2.89,2.3-3.26
  c3.47-1.05,6.86-3.85,5.61-6.99c-0.17-0.46-0.38-0.84-0.59-1.21h25.23V299h15.81c0.17,6.02,3.43,19.29,1,28.45
  C337.16,332.47,338.75,336.57,341.09,339.04z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Renton" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M338.29,368.78l-11.5,19.03h-28.03v-9.75h-9.96v-25.02c3.14-0.71,8.95-6.36,8.58-11.67
  c0-0.13,0-0.25-0.04-0.38h14.43v27.94h15.98v-0.17H338.29z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="SeaTac" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M291.31,378.07v5.44H278.3l-1.63-3.72l-5.81-8.12l-1.25-3.81l0.04-13.6l-0.75-3.68l-0.67-1.17h17.95
  c0.54,2.26,1.21,3.77,2.09,3.72c0.17,0,0.33-0.04,0.54-0.08v25.02H291.31z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Tacoma" fill="#FC9A1A" points="288.8,394.13 281.52,449.39 268.22,449.39 259.6,438.85 229.77,442.95 226.59,439.48 
  230.52,430.53 233.33,419.19 233.2,407.48 236.88,410.78 244.33,415.51 252.19,422.37 255.46,423.46 258.59,422.03 262.44,418.39 
  258.8,415.84 256.63,413.54 256.25,410.95 257.84,407.48 260.56,404.63 264.41,401.91 268.51,399.9 275.45,397.9 277.79,394.55 
  278.17,392.83 280.56,392.42  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Lakewood" fill="#FC9A1A" points="263.11,443.16 263.11,458.47 232.99,458.47 232.99,442.49 259.6,438.85  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Federal_Way" fill="#FC9A1A" points="298.75,378.07 298.75,397.56 288.34,397.56 288.8,394.13 280.56,392.42 278.17,392.83 
  278.84,389.7 278.46,383.92 278.3,383.51 291.31,383.51 291.31,378.07  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Auburn" fill="#FC9A1A" points="314.94,409.57 314.94,431.28 283.9,431.28 287.42,404.55  "/>
</g>
<g id="Issaquah">
 <path fill="#FC9A1A" d="M383.59,330.88v37.9h-55.85V341h13.34v-1.97c3.39,3.68,8.37,3.72,7.57-2.18c-0.29-2.22-0.33-4.18-0.29-5.98
  H383.59z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Newcastle" x="311.76" y="341" fill="#FC9A1A" width="15.98" height="27.94"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Camano_Island" fill="#FC9A1A" points="273.61,174.38 269.8,174.46 267.34,172.45 263.32,165.68 261.35,163.71 243.41,150.12 
  239.02,144.68 235.67,137.23 234.12,129.2 234.54,121.63 237.01,115.27 241.48,111.08 248.64,108.83 252.74,108.49 256.17,109.08 
  258.64,111.5 260.48,114.72 262.36,116.69 262.36,121.33 258.93,119.79 257.88,119.03 256.5,117.69 254.87,116.9 253.11,117.61 
  252.11,120.66 252.69,127.23 248.34,130.45 247.72,135.26 248.51,141 250.23,145.89 252.28,148.9 255.71,152.67 259.43,155.85 
  262.57,157.18 265.91,159.32 269.14,164.34  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Bremerton" fill="#FC9A1A" points="219.98,321.26 221.57,323.6 216.3,326.32 210.57,319.46 202.54,301.85 201.11,304.06 197.1,293.73 
  206.89,277 207.51,280.93 209.02,283.02 210.94,284.48 212.83,286.79 213.83,288.84 221.57,319.08  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Poulsbo" fill="#FC9A1A" points="247.97,268.76 246.88,271.43 245.54,273.4 244.87,274.91 242.74,275.49 232.45,273.06 
  228.85,273.86 229.31,277.54 227.43,282.69 224.25,287.2 220.78,289.13 208.89,276.37 206.89,277 201.57,286.12 190.99,274.15 
  191.37,273.19 212.45,242.44 214.84,240.1 217.09,239.1 220.82,240.06 221.15,242.44 220.52,245.29 221.57,247.71 226.09,248.72 
  227.05,244.12 226.01,236.96 222.41,221.9 221.57,219.6 217.55,211.9 217.09,208.77 229.81,216.71 235.25,221.57 237.47,229.35 
  237.72,233.99 239.06,244.7 240.31,247.88 242.53,250.6 243.37,253.78 240.35,258.76 242.28,259.38 244.5,260.68 246.5,262.56 
  247.76,265.03  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Port_Orchard" fill="#FC9A1A" points="233.83,340.71 230.27,345.39 209.36,341 210.11,337.32 213.45,335.69 218.39,332.22 222.91,327.91 
  229.9,323.43 231.99,328.66 232.36,336.78  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Sammamish" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M386.9,290.13v46.1h-3.3v-5.35h-35.22c0.17-7.7,2.22-12.76-2.72-21.92c-2.59-4.81-3.77-7.95-4.39-9.96h1.92
  v-5.27h18.32v-3.6H386.9z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Tulalip" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M306.53,183.71l0.42-0.5l-0.38-1.42l-1.76-0.92l-1.25-1.21l-3.01-0.17l-3.51,3.77l-14.85-12.42l-6.9-7.86
  l-4.69-10.33l-1.17-11.84l0.42-9.83l-1.92-6.65c9.54,0.59,26.77,1.97,33.89,3.93c4.56,8.07,5.61,41.25,5.81,55.68L306.53,183.71z"
  />
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Marysville" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M322.81,128.24v52.33h-0.21v4.14h-11.63v-0.08l-3.35-0.71c-0.21-14.43-1.25-47.61-5.81-55.68H322.81z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Mill_Creek" fill="#FC9A1A" points="341.09,248.97 341.09,282.18 325.15,282.18 325.15,259.43 327.45,250.93 336.15,250.93 
  336.15,248.97  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Snohomish" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M428.31,240.14l-4.56,31.88h-34.26l-2.38,17.44c-0.13,0.46-0.21,0.67-0.21,0.67H361.5v-8.87h-20.41v-32.3
  h-4.94v-21.34c3.56,3.39,1.42,5.35,12.47,6.74c11.59,1.51,41.33-2.13,50.33-1.88h0.46c5.48,0.13,15.35-1.46,20.88,1.88
  C423.88,236.38,424.88,236.46,428.31,240.14z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Lake_Stevens" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M398.99,128.24v104.25c-8.95-0.25-38.78,3.39-50.37,1.88c-11.04-1.38-8.91-3.35-12.47-6.74v-47.06h-13.34
  v-52.33H398.99z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Monroe" fill="#FC9A1A" points="509.18,250.93 482.49,290.13 442.75,299 435.8,272.02 423.75,272.02 428.31,240.14  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Granite_Falls" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M450.44,159.11v84l-22.13-2.97c-3.43-3.68-4.43-3.77-8.03-5.77c-5.52-3.35-15.4-1.76-20.88-1.88h-0.42
  v-73.38H450.44z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Carnation" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M419.11,304.27v6.53H386.9v-20.67c0,0,0.08-0.21,0.21-0.67L419.11,304.27z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Fall_City" x="386.9" y="310.8" fill="#FC9A1A" width="32.21" height="25.43"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Kent" fill="#FC9A1A" points="383.59,368.78 376.94,420.9 314.94,409.57 287.42,404.55 286.54,404.38 286.54,387.81 
  326.78,387.81 338.29,368.78  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Duvall" fill="#FC9A1A" points="442.75,299 419.11,304.27 387.11,289.46 389.49,272.02 435.8,272.02  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Stanwood" fill="#FC9A1A" d="M355.9,90.59v37.65h-54.09c-7.11-1.97-24.35-3.35-33.89-3.93l-0.17-0.59l-5.4-2.38v-4.64l2.51-1.42l-1-3.31
  l0.67-3.22l3.26-6.57l-0.88-1.67l-0.5-3.47l-0.88-2.22l-1.25-1.92l-2.51-2.3H355.9z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Arlington" fill="#FC9A1A" points="435.01,108.49 435.01,159.11 398.99,159.11 398.99,128.24 355.9,128.24 355.9,108.49  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Snoqualmie" fill="#FC9A1A" points="424.72,392.42 382.38,378.15 383.59,368.78 383.59,336.23 419.11,336.23  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="North_Bend" fill="#FC9A1A" points="450.44,366.48 450.44,397.56 424.72,392.42 421.91,364.35  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Rural_South_Sound" fill="#FC9A1A" points="398.99,436.17 398.99,498.21 319.75,498.21 263.11,458.47 263.11,443.16 268.22,449.39 
  281.52,449.39 283.9,431.28 314.94,431.28 314.94,409.57 376.94,420.9  "/>
</g>
<rect x="173.42" y="47.54" fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="346.13" height="470.5"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M173.42,491.8c50.91-12.09,71.36-42.78,70.77-53.42
 c-0.59-10.64,15.33,3.55,23.59-4.73c8.26-8.28,14.15-27.79,13.56-35.48c-0.59-7.69-4.05-16.56,0.04-20.7
 c4.09-4.14,5.27-18.92,3.5-23.65c-1.77-4.73-6-10.81-6.29-20.27c-0.3-9.46-6.09-32.95-6.98-42.41
 c-0.89-9.46,10.73-39.03,14.07-40.21c3.33-1.18,19.25-33.11,20.43-43.17c1.18-10.05,4.72-56.18-2.36-74.51
 c-7.08-18.33-23.2-42.67-24-85.72"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M285.68,250.93c4.13,3.55,16.9,11.24,18.07,17.15s-1.77,49.08,0,52.63
 c1.77,3.55,2.34,11.24,0.29,17.15s-1.05,23.06-5.68,26.61c-4.63,3.55-12.88,0-12.88,0"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M518.68,290.13c-10.45,4.49-34.2,2.62-50.62-4.86
 c-16.42-7.48-32.84-44.91-47.77-50.89c-14.93-5.99-59.72,5.99-71.66,0s-42.51-26.61-42.51-26.61"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M518.68,427.58c-14.83-0.74-35.58-30.48-38.55-40.14
 c-2.97-9.66-45.96-3.72-45.96-3.72s-20.02-11.89-32.62-11.89s-25.2-15.61-34.84-22.3c-9.64-6.69-26.69,0.46-28.91-5.35
 c-2.22-5.8-31.68-16.21-31.68-16.21"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution just in case anyone needs it in the future. I realized that I wasn't creating an array to work from. I also needed conditional statements.

```js
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("select")
    .change(function() {
      var value = jQuery(this).val();

      if (jQuery.inArray("Seattle", value) !== -1) {
        jQuery("#Seattle").css("fill", "#f94e32");
      } else {
        jQuery("#Seattle").css("fill", "#dddddd");
      }
      if (jQuery.inArray("Tacoma", value) !== -1) {
        jQuery("#Tacoma").css("fill", "#f94e32");
      } else {
        jQuery("#Tacoma").css("fill", "#dddddd");
      }
      if (jQuery.inArray("Bellevue", value) !== -1) {
        jQuery("#Bellevue").css("fill", "#f94e32");
      } else {
        jQuery("#Bellevue").css("fill", "#dddddd");
      }
 
    })
    .change();
});
```

```css
svg {width:400px;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="item_meta[82][]" id="field_trf7c" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." aria-required="true" data-invmsg="Service Area is invalid" data-sectionid="49" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select options" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="Seattle" class="">
   Seattle  </option>
   <option value="Tacoma" class="">
   Tacoma  </option>
   <option value="Bellevue" class="">
   Bellevue  </option>
   <option value="Everett" class="">
   Everett  </option>
   <option value="Arlington" class="">
   Arlington  </option>
   <option value="Auburn" class="">
   Auburn  </option>
   <option value="Bainbridge Island" class="">
   Bainbridge Island  </option>
   <option value="Beaux Arts Village" class="">
   Beaux Arts Village  </option>
   <option value="Bonney Lake" class="">
   Bonney Lake  </option>
   <option value="Bothell" class="">
   Bothell  </option>
   <option value="Bremerton" class="">
   Bremerton  </option>
   <option value="Brier" class="">
   Brier  </option>
   <option value="Burien" class="">
   Burien  </option>
   <option value="Covington" class="">
   Covington  </option>
   <option value="Des Moines" class="">
   Des Moines  </option>
   <option value="Duvall" class="">
   Duvall  </option>
   <option value="Enumclaw" class="">
   Enumclaw  </option>
   <option value="Edmonds" class="">
   Edmonds  </option>
   <option value="Federal Way" class="">
   Federal Way  </option>
   <option value="Gig Harbor" class="">
   Gig Harbor  </option>
   <option value="Gold Bar" class="">
   Gold Bar  </option>
   <option value="Granite Falls" class="">
   Granite Falls  </option>
   <option value="Issaquah" class="">
   Issaquah  </option>
   <option value="Kenmore" class="">
   Kenmore  </option>
   <option value="Kent" class="">
   Kent  </option>
   <option value="Kirkland" class="">
   Kirkland  </option>
   <option value="Lake Forest Park" class="">
   Lake Forest Park  </option>
   <option value="Lake Stevens" class="">
   Lake Stevens  </option>
   <option value="Lakewood" class="">
   Lakewood  </option>
   <option value="Lynnwood" class="">
   Lynnwood  </option>
   <option value="Maple Valley" class="">
   Maple Valley  </option>
   <option value="Marysville" class="">
   Marysville  </option>
   <option value="Mercer Island" class="">
   Mercer Island  </option>
   <option value="Mill Creek" class="">
   Mill Creek  </option>
   <option value="Monroe" class="">
   Monroe  </option>
   <option value="Mountlake Terrace" class="">
   Mountlake Terrace  </option>
   <option value="Mount Vernon" class="">
   Mount Vernon  </option>
   <option value="Mukilteo" class="">
   Mukilteo  </option>
   <option value="Newcastle" class="">
   Newcastle  </option>
   <option value="Normandy Park" class="">
   Normandy Park  </option>
   <option value="Puyallup" class="">
   Puyallup  </option>
   <option value="Poulsbo" class="">
   Poulsbo  </option>
   <option value="Redmond" class="">
   Redmond  </option>
   <option value="Renton" class="">
   Renton  </option>
   <option value="Sammamish" class="">
   Sammamish  </option>
   <option value="SeaTac" class="">
   SeaTac  </option>
   <option value="Shoreline" class="">
   Shoreline  </option>
   <option value="Silverdale" class="">
   Silverdale  </option>
   <option value="Snohomish" class="">
   Snohomish  </option>
   <option value="Stanwood" class="">
   Stanwood  </option>
   <option value="Sultan" class="">
   Sultan  </option>
   <option value="Tukwila" class="">
   Tukwila  </option>
   <option value="Woodinville" class="">
   Woodinville  </option>
   <option value="Woodway" class="">
   Woodway  </option>
  </select>
<svg version="1.1" id="Washington" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="173.42 47.54 345.26 470.5" enable-background="new 173.42 47.54 345.26 470.5" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#878787" d="M175.68,47.54h-2.26v8.83l1.05-1.09l1.5-4.73L175.68,47.54z M203.46,176.14l-2.05-7.83l-3.1-7.74l-1.71-1.46
 h-2.05l-2.22,1.71l3.68,4.19l2.22,6.15l-0.04,4.81l-3.1,0.29l-0.84-2.09l-0.58-6.78l-1.34-2.17l-2.05,0.12l-0.42,2.64l0.88,5.9
 l1.25,4.22l2.85,6.19l3.68,4.81l4.02,0.17l1.75-5.23L203.46,176.14z M214.33,226.63l-11.08-14.6l-0.96-2.68l-0.67-6.73l-0.55-2.51
 l-1.5-1.8l-4.06-2.68l-1.72-2.01l-8.99-16.19l-1.34-4.64l-0.96-2.01l-1.93-2.38l-1.59-3.14l0.09-4.44l1.5-1.92l5.23-2.97l2.05-1.59
 l-4.22-7.61l-5.27-0.05l-4.94,2.56v99.27l0.13-3.06l2.51-4.18l1.42,11.59l-0.17,9.37l-3.89,20.25v10.41l1.3,0.59l2.46-0.5l2.35-1.47
 l1.8-2.38l0.67-3.31l0.54-5.14l1.38-6.07l3.93-11.54l2.97-6.28l9.46-12.09l1.75-3.35l1.59-5.98l1.8-2.76l2.09-0.54l6.36-0.34
 l1.76-1.29L214.33,226.63z M233.95,341l-0.12-0.29l-3.56,4.68L209.36,341l0.75-3.68l-7.57,3.68l1.17-3.18l4.06-4.43l2.05-3.31
 l1.79-3.97l-0.04-0.71h-1.63l-7.45-4.23l-1.79-1.92l-1.22-4.27l-0.25-4.1l0.5-3.47l1.13-2.97l0.25-0.38l-4.01-10.33l4.47-7.61
 l-10.58-11.97l-1.55,3.98l-3.01,14.09l-1.38,4.15L182.5,299l-4.85,2.85l-4.23,1.71v82.12l2.64-3.89l-1.18,4.39l0.97,2.3l1.8,1.59
 l1.42,2.22l1.17,4.39l0.33,2.39l0.09,8.66l-0.55,5.94l-1.92,4.89l-4.1,1.97v7.32l3.43,14.39l5.56,9.96l6.32-5.86l0.08-1.88
 l-0.58-2.22l-0.71-1.8l-0.34-0.67l0.71-1.34l1.18-1.63l0.96-0.71l0.04,1.55l1.25-2.64l1.38-1.42l0.21-1.84l-5.18-9.04l-1.13-4.35
 l0.96-4.43l3.3-5.4l0.84-2.51l0.25-3.14l0.42-2.63l1.42-1.13l1.88-0.84l1.59-1.88l1.47-2.26l1.67-1.84l7.41-3.85l2.76-2.93
 l1.59-5.85l1.13,7.74l-2.3,5.27l-3.18,4.39l-1.59,5.19l-1.8,4.14l-2.97,2.84l-0.63,2.85l5.4,4.18l16.52,7.41l3.18,0.04l2.47-6.4
 l-0.8-5.23l-5.35-11l3.68-1.22l2.85-2.01l2.17-3.09l1.59-4.39l-3.97-6.74l0.96-6.94l2.84-7.37l1.68-8.03l1.67-5.9l2.8-6.65
 l0.38-5.48L233.95,341z M241.65,47.54l-0.58,0.33l-1.09-0.33h-33.97l-0.75,2.01l-2.14,2.05l-1,2.8l2.09,5.27l2.51,2.34l3.26,0.8
 l3.43-0.46l3.18-1.51l1.63-1.96l3.43-5.74l1.55-1.21l2.18,0.21l3.26,1l1.46,1.97l-3.17,3.35v2.38l2.88,2.76l4.23,8.58l2.34,1.8
 l3.51,0.29l3.14,0.96l2.76,1.68l4.98,5.52l6.36,3.93l4.64,4.23h94.13v17.9h79.11v50.62h15.43v84l58.74,7.82l-26.69,39.2
 l-63.38,14.14v31.96l2.8,28.12l28.53,2.13v31.08l-25.72-5.14l-42.34-14.27l-5.44,42.75l22.05,15.27v62.04h-79.24l-56.64-39.74
 h-30.12v-15.98l-3.22,0.46l-3.18-3.47l-0.63,1.38l-17.23,25.39l-7.16,7.41l-7.78,4.68l-0.83-3.43l-2.01-3.47l-2.64-2.68l-5.23-2.42
 l-2-3.1l-1.68-3.56l-1.75-2.67l-4.06-2.51l-0.17,0.25v63.29h346.13V47.54H241.65z M203.79,451.15l-2.13-1.3l-4.23-0.46l-2.72,0.46
 l-1.21,2.68l-1.17,3.05l-1.84,1.34l-1.8,1.34l0.92,3.1l0.88,0.42l3.01,3.13l1.8,1.34l1.84,1.3h1.21l2.39-1.76l2.76-3.09l0.88-4.9
 l0.29-3.05L203.79,451.15z"/>
<g>
 <polygon id="Whidbey_Island" fill="#DDDDDD" points="273.9,207.3 273.32,208.77 272.06,210.02 270.31,213.24 270.26,213.33 268.13,217.26 
  267.13,218.68 266.37,220.86 265.37,221.78 264.03,221.73 263.66,220.06 263.45,218.09 262.44,217.26 257.8,219.39 255,220.02 
  253.74,218.43 253.28,211.61 251.94,204.5 249.64,198.64 246.29,195.76 243.66,196.3 239.73,200.86 237.47,202.32 234.75,201.95 
  232.87,200.44 230.98,197.97 228.01,195.63 224.12,190.02 221.32,183.54 221.57,178.23 217.81,172.37 216.72,167.77 219.86,150.2 
  218.35,142.71 215,139.62 210.44,140.24 205.3,143.71 200.03,134.26 198.6,132.8 196.39,132.08 193.58,130.29 190.86,128.07 
  189.19,126.1 186.68,118.49 187.64,111.96 205.3,75.9 207.85,68.83 213.33,68.96 216.34,67.37 218.73,64.52 220.82,63.44 
  222.78,66.95 223.2,69.33 223.54,70.34 224.37,71.34 224.67,77.91 237.8,89 237.47,97.91 234.62,101.17 231.32,101.96 
  227.97,100.42 225.04,96.78 221.19,93.47 217.97,96.32 215.55,101.8 214.04,106.48 211.11,99.87 209.94,102.13 209.56,107.95 
  208.94,112 205.84,114.51 193.54,117.15 196.43,121.08 199.4,121.54 206.01,119.53 208.85,120.29 213.83,123.38 216.3,124.09 
  220.86,126.23 224.04,131.62 226.09,138.69 228.72,153.04 229.56,170.61 231.28,186.18 233.66,189.73 236.51,187.77 239.06,180.4 
  236.34,173.46 236.09,166.35 238.22,162.75 242.7,166.3 246.13,170.86 249.72,174.59 266.58,186.59 269.89,191.7 271.19,199.02 
  273.07,204  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Vashon_Island" fill="#DDDDDD" points="269.6,386.27 268.01,386.35 258.76,390.28 251.98,397.52 247.76,401.08 246.63,396.93 
  246.8,392.75 248.39,389.53 251.4,388.23 253.53,386.56 254.03,383.34 252.65,380.91 249.1,381.79 250.69,383.92 246.5,385.97 
  244.33,387.44 243.41,389.28 243.32,395.6 242.86,398.61 241.94,401.08 240.48,402.58 238.97,402.41 237.3,400.74 235.42,397.94 
  234.5,394.59 235.33,391.62 236.71,389.15 237.47,387.23 239.06,363.55 240.4,359.91 243.58,355.1 247.38,351 250.69,349.41 
  249.31,353.85 250.23,355.94 252.15,357.44 253.74,360.16 254.2,363.43 254.41,369.83 255.04,373.01 257.76,378.36 261.23,381 
  265.24,382.96  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Bainbridge_Island" fill="#DDDDDD" points="245.42,322.3 243.62,324.06 241.48,327.24 236.76,326.36 232.2,319.58 228.93,318.83 
  226.17,319.42 224.62,317.7 226.38,312.47 226.8,308.83 225.29,306.24 224.33,302.81 224.04,298.29 224.37,296.28 228.01,291.18 
  228.85,287.96 228.64,284.74 228.89,282.27 231.02,281.26 233.16,281.97 235.54,283.69 237.63,285.87 238.89,287.92 239.98,298.21 
  241.32,302.81 243.37,305.15 241.65,307.58 240.52,308.71 238.89,309.46 241.15,312.1 241.07,314.48 241.86,315.94 242.28,317.7 
  242.65,320 243.62,321.47  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Seattle" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M286.16,349.41h-17.95l-1.72-2.97l-1.51-3.35l-4.06-14.22l-0.33-2.8l1.13-2.22l2.84-3.68l2.68-0.79
  l2.38,3.3l2.3,4.52l2.18,2.89l1-6.53l0.21-5.06l-1.09-4.1l-3.05-3.72l-9.54-4.31l-2.01-1.34l-2.09-2.97l-1.13-2.93l0.75-1.38
  l2.47-0.88l0.92-2.18l0.54-2.8l1.34-2.76l3.35-5.35l0.79-3.51l-0.63-5.23l-0.46-2.89h15.02c-0.88,6.15-0.21,16.82,2.34,17.74
  c3.39,1.25,4.64,0,4.73,2.26c0.13,2.3-4.6,9.45-6.44,9.16c-1.84-0.25-4.89-2.26-4.81-0.5c0.04,1.8,4.31,1.97,4.48,4.98
  c0.13,2.97-1.59,14.77-0.67,18.45c0.88,3.68,4.94,3.14,4.56,7.07C284.45,334.1,284.82,343.93,286.16,349.41z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Shoreline" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M280.56,272.02c-0.04,0.04-0.04,0.08-0.04,0.13H265.5l-0.29-2.05l-2.34-3.35l-1.59-4.69h15.77
  L280.56,272.02z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Lake_Forest_Park" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M282.77,262.06v5.61c-0.5,0.13-0.88,0.29-0.88,0.29c-0.63,0.5-1.09,2.01-1.34,4.06l-3.51-9.96H282.77z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Edmonds" fill="#DDDDDD" points="272.02,237.76 272.02,262.06 261.27,262.06 261.23,261.98 261.61,255.75 262.65,250.6 
  264.24,246.29 266.33,242.65  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Mountlake_Terrace" x="272.02" y="254.82" fill="#DDDDDD" width="10.75" height="7.24"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Kenmore" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M288.38,262.06v11.63h-5.31c0-0.54,0.13-1,0.33-1.38c0.04-0.04,0.08-0.13,0.08-0.17
  c1.97-3.31,1.59-3.64,0.84-4.31c-0.42-0.33-1-0.29-1.55-0.17v-5.61H288.38z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Lynnwood" fill="#DDDDDD" points="295.07,258.26 295.07,262.06 282.77,262.06 282.77,254.82 272.02,254.82 272.02,237.76 
  294.07,237.76 286.54,250.26  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Brier" x="288.38" y="262.06" fill="#DDDDDD" width="6.69" height="11.63"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Bothell" fill="#DDDDDD" points="312.43,261.23 308.04,261.23 308.04,273.69 295.07,273.69 295.07,258.26 286.54,250.26 
  294.07,237.76 311.97,237.76  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Everett" fill="#DDDDDD" points="336.15,180.57 336.15,250.93 327.45,250.93 327.74,249.89 312.22,249.89 311.97,237.76 
  283.82,237.76 278.13,218.6 278.13,216.71 278.63,215.63 278.63,212.49 279.51,209.98 281.18,208.39 285.41,205.13 286.91,203.41 
  288.71,201.95 293.15,200.94 296.29,200.23 298.17,198.47 302.44,195.8 303.23,191.7 303.61,187.05 304.99,185.55 305.95,184.38 
  306.53,183.71 310.97,184.63 310.97,184.71 322.6,184.71 322.6,180.57  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Mukilteo" fill="#DDDDDD" points="283.82,237.76 272.02,237.76 272.65,237.21 275.41,231.94 275.95,224.96 276.58,220.02 
  278.13,216.71 278.13,218.6  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Wodinville" fill="#DDDDDD" points="327.74,249.89 325.15,259.43 312.43,261.52 312.43,273.69 308.04,273.69 308.04,261.23 
  310.72,261.23 310.72,249.89  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Kirkland" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M325.15,259.43v34.3h-28.74c-1.21-2.22-2.76-3.1-2.8-4.31c-0.08-1.42,3.3-4.23,2.34-5.77
  c-1-1.55-4.27,4.06-6.02,2.72c-0.21-0.17-0.5-0.46-0.84-0.84c-2.13-2.34-6.28-8.37-6.02-11.84h29.37v-12.17L325.15,259.43z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Mercer_Island" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M296.41,333.32c0,6.67-2.09,12.07-4.67,12.07c-2.58,0-0.94-4.23-4.67-12.07
  c-2.87-6.02,2.09-12.07,4.67-12.07C294.32,321.25,296.41,326.65,296.41,333.32z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Redmond" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M361.5,281.26v12.47h-18.32V299h-1.92c-1.09-3.51-0.46-3.6-2.72-3.26c-0.84,0.13-1.13,1.34-1.09,3.26
  h-15.81v-5.27h3.51v-11.55h15.94v-0.92H361.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Bellevue" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M341.09,339.04V341h-43.76c-0.17-5.35,4.73-7.2,4.56-10.83c-0.17-3.68-5.56-7.91-5.48-11.09
  c0.04-3.18-2.68-5.4-5.48-5.98c-0.88-0.17-1.46-1.21-1.84-2.59c-0.38-1.55-0.42-3.6,0-5.31c0.38-1.59,1.13-2.89,2.3-3.26
  c3.47-1.05,6.86-3.85,5.61-6.99c-0.17-0.46-0.38-0.84-0.59-1.21h25.23V299h15.81c0.17,6.02,3.43,19.29,1,28.45
  C337.16,332.47,338.75,336.57,341.09,339.04z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Renton" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M338.29,368.78l-11.5,19.03h-28.03v-9.75h-9.96v-25.02c3.14-0.71,8.95-6.36,8.58-11.67
  c0-0.13,0-0.25-0.04-0.38h14.43v27.94h15.98v-0.17H338.29z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="SeaTac" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M291.31,378.07v5.44H278.3l-1.63-3.72l-5.81-8.12l-1.25-3.81l0.04-13.6l-0.75-3.68l-0.67-1.17h17.95
  c0.54,2.26,1.21,3.77,2.09,3.72c0.17,0,0.33-0.04,0.54-0.08v25.02H291.31z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Tacoma" fill="#DDDDDD" points="288.8,394.13 281.52,449.39 268.22,449.39 259.6,438.85 229.77,442.95 226.59,439.48 
  230.52,430.53 233.33,419.19 233.2,407.48 236.88,410.78 244.33,415.51 252.19,422.37 255.46,423.46 258.59,422.03 262.44,418.39 
  258.8,415.84 256.63,413.54 256.25,410.95 257.84,407.48 260.56,404.63 264.41,401.91 268.51,399.9 275.45,397.9 277.79,394.55 
  278.17,392.83 280.56,392.42  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Lakewood" fill="#DDDDDD" points="263.11,443.16 263.11,458.47 232.99,458.47 232.99,442.49 259.6,438.85  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Federal_Way" fill="#DDDDDD" points="298.75,378.07 298.75,397.56 288.34,397.56 288.8,394.13 280.56,392.42 278.17,392.83 
  278.84,389.7 278.46,383.92 278.3,383.51 291.31,383.51 291.31,378.07  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Auburn" fill="#DDDDDD" points="314.94,409.57 314.94,431.28 283.9,431.28 287.42,404.55  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Issaquah" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M383.59,330.88v37.9h-55.85V341h13.34v-1.97c3.39,3.68,8.37,3.72,7.57-2.18c-0.29-2.22-0.33-4.18-0.29-5.98
  H383.59z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Newcastle" x="311.76" y="341" fill="#DDDDDD" width="15.98" height="27.94"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Camano_Island" fill="#DDDDDD" points="273.61,174.38 269.8,174.46 267.34,172.45 263.32,165.68 261.35,163.71 243.41,150.12 
  239.02,144.68 235.67,137.23 234.12,129.2 234.54,121.63 237.01,115.27 241.48,111.08 248.64,108.83 252.74,108.49 256.17,109.08 
  258.64,111.5 260.48,114.72 262.36,116.69 262.36,121.33 258.93,119.79 257.88,119.03 256.5,117.69 254.87,116.9 253.11,117.61 
  252.11,120.66 252.69,127.23 248.34,130.45 247.72,135.26 248.51,141 250.23,145.89 252.28,148.9 255.71,152.67 259.43,155.85 
  262.57,157.18 265.91,159.32 269.14,164.34  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Bremerton" fill="#DDDDDD" points="219.98,321.26 221.57,323.6 216.3,326.32 210.57,319.46 202.54,301.85 201.11,304.06 197.1,293.73 
  206.89,277 207.51,280.93 209.02,283.02 210.94,284.48 212.83,286.79 213.83,288.84 221.57,319.08  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Poulsbo" fill="#DDDDDD" points="247.97,268.76 246.88,271.43 245.54,273.4 244.87,274.91 242.74,275.49 232.45,273.06 
  228.85,273.86 229.31,277.54 227.43,282.69 224.25,287.2 220.78,289.13 208.89,276.37 206.89,277 201.57,286.12 190.99,274.15 
  191.37,273.19 212.45,242.44 214.84,240.1 217.09,239.1 220.82,240.06 221.15,242.44 220.52,245.29 221.57,247.71 226.09,248.72 
  227.05,244.12 226.01,236.96 222.41,221.9 221.57,219.6 217.55,211.9 217.09,208.77 229.81,216.71 235.25,221.57 237.47,229.35 
  237.72,233.99 239.06,244.7 240.31,247.88 242.53,250.6 243.37,253.78 240.35,258.76 242.28,259.38 244.5,260.68 246.5,262.56 
  247.76,265.03  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Port_Orchard" fill="#DDDDDD" points="233.83,340.71 230.27,345.39 209.36,341 210.11,337.32 213.45,335.69 218.39,332.22 222.91,327.91 
  229.9,323.43 231.99,328.66 232.36,336.78  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Sammamish" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M386.9,290.13v46.1h-3.3v-5.35h-35.22c0.17-7.7,2.22-12.76-2.72-21.92c-2.59-4.81-3.77-7.95-4.39-9.96h1.92
  v-5.27h18.32v-3.6H386.9z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Tulalip" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M306.53,183.71l0.42-0.5l-0.38-1.42l-1.76-0.92l-1.25-1.21l-3.01-0.17l-3.51,3.77l-14.85-12.42l-6.9-7.86
  l-4.69-10.33l-1.17-11.84l0.42-9.83l-1.92-6.65c9.54,0.59,26.77,1.97,33.89,3.93c4.56,8.07,5.61,41.25,5.81,55.68L306.53,183.71z"
  />
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Marysville" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M322.81,128.24v52.33h-0.21v4.14h-11.63v-0.08l-3.35-0.71c-0.21-14.43-1.25-47.61-5.81-55.68H322.81z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Mill_Creek" fill="#DDDDDD" points="341.09,248.97 341.09,282.18 325.15,282.18 325.15,259.43 327.45,250.93 336.15,250.93 
  336.15,248.97  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Snohomish" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M428.31,240.14l-4.56,31.88h-34.26l-2.38,17.44c-0.13,0.46-0.21,0.67-0.21,0.67H361.5v-8.87h-20.41v-32.3
  h-4.94v-21.34c3.56,3.39,1.42,5.35,12.47,6.74c11.59,1.51,41.33-2.13,50.33-1.88h0.46c5.48,0.13,15.35-1.46,20.88,1.88
  C423.88,236.38,424.88,236.46,428.31,240.14z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Lake_Stevens" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M398.99,128.24v104.25c-8.95-0.25-38.78,3.39-50.37,1.88c-11.04-1.38-8.91-3.35-12.47-6.74v-47.06h-13.34
  v-52.33H398.99z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Monroe" fill="#DDDDDD" points="509.18,250.93 482.49,290.13 442.75,299 435.8,272.02 423.75,272.02 428.31,240.14  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Granite_Falls" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M450.44,159.11v84l-22.13-2.97c-3.43-3.68-4.43-3.77-8.03-5.77c-5.52-3.35-15.4-1.76-20.88-1.88h-0.42
  v-73.38H450.44z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Carnation" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M419.11,304.27v6.53H386.9v-20.67c0,0,0.08-0.21,0.21-0.67L419.11,304.27z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect id="Fall_City" x="386.9" y="310.8" fill="#DDDDDD" width="32.21" height="25.43"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Kent" fill="#DDDDDD" points="383.59,368.78 376.94,420.9 314.94,409.57 287.42,404.55 286.54,404.38 286.54,387.81 
  326.78,387.81 338.29,368.78  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Duvall" fill="#DDDDDD" points="442.75,299 419.11,304.27 387.11,289.46 389.49,272.02 435.8,272.02  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="Stanwood" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M355.9,90.59v37.65h-54.09c-7.11-1.97-24.35-3.35-33.89-3.93l-0.17-0.59l-5.4-2.38v-4.64l2.51-1.42l-1-3.31
  l0.67-3.22l3.26-6.57l-0.88-1.67l-0.5-3.47l-0.88-2.22l-1.25-1.92l-2.51-2.3H355.9z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Arlington" fill="#DDDDDD" points="435.01,108.49 435.01,159.11 398.99,159.11 398.99,128.24 355.9,128.24 355.9,108.49  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Snoqualmie" fill="#DDDDDD" points="424.72,392.42 382.38,378.15 383.59,368.78 383.59,336.23 419.11,336.23  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="North_Bend" fill="#DDDDDD" points="450.44,366.48 450.44,397.56 424.72,392.42 421.91,364.35  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon id="Rural_South_Sound" fill="#DDDDDD" points="398.99,436.17 398.99,498.21 319.75,498.21 263.11,458.47 263.11,443.16 268.22,449.39 
  281.52,449.39 283.9,431.28 314.94,431.28 314.94,409.57 376.94,420.9  "/>
</g>
<rect x="173.42" y="47.54" fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="346.13" height="470.5"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M173.42,491.8c50.91-12.09,71.36-42.78,70.77-53.42
 c-0.59-10.64,15.33,3.55,23.59-4.73c8.26-8.28,14.15-27.79,13.56-35.48c-0.59-7.69-4.05-16.56,0.04-20.7
 c4.09-4.14,5.27-18.92,3.5-23.65c-1.77-4.73-6-10.81-6.29-20.27c-0.3-9.46-6.09-32.95-6.98-42.41
 c-0.89-9.46,10.73-39.03,14.07-40.21c3.33-1.18,19.25-33.11,20.43-43.17c1.18-10.05,4.72-56.18-2.36-74.51
 c-7.08-18.33-23.2-42.67-24-85.72"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M285.68,250.93c4.13,3.55,16.9,11.24,18.07,17.15s-1.77,49.08,0,52.63
 c1.77,3.55,2.34,11.24,0.29,17.15s-1.05,23.06-5.68,26.61c-4.63,3.55-12.88,0-12.88,0"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M518.68,290.13c-10.45,4.49-34.2,2.62-50.62-4.86
 c-16.42-7.48-32.84-44.91-47.77-50.89c-14.93-5.99-59.72,5.99-71.66,0s-42.51-26.61-42.51-26.61"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#636363" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M518.68,427.58c-14.83-0.74-35.58-30.48-38.55-40.14
 c-2.97-9.66-45.96-3.72-45.96-3.72s-20.02-11.89-32.62-11.89s-25.2-15.61-34.84-22.3c-9.64-6.69-26.69,0.46-28.91-5.35
 c-2.22-5.8-31.68-16.21-31.68-16.21"/>
</svg>
```

The full code is too long for here. Check it out here: https://codepen.io/handsomemeatball/pen/zYGvrNy